# Electron-build with Appx missing icone

Tags: electron, electron-builder, appx

When I build my app and try to run the appx file I'm missing my icons.

I've tried having the images booth in my assets file and my build folder called electron-build/appx as mention at https://www.electron.build/configuration/appx.

What can I try more than this?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple in my case.

In my assets folder i needed to change the name from win to appx and the appx build took those images.